# im trying to merge two sorted linked list in ascending order but im not getting the correct output

Tags: c, sorting, merge, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to merge two sorted linked lists but I'm not getting any output,
I'm trying to traverse through the two linked list while comparing the data and adding the smaller element to my final linked list.
I'm using `pushback()` to add the element at the end:

```
void merge_sort(struct node *a, struct node *b)
{
    struct node *ans = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    ans = NULL;
    while (a != NULL || b != NULL)
    {
        if ((a->data >= b->data) || (a == NULL && b != NULL))
        {
            pushback(&ans, b->data);
            b = b->next;
            // display(ans);
        }
        if ((b->data > a->data) || (b == NULL && a != NULL))
        {
            pushback(&ans, a->data);
            a = a->next;
            // display(ans);
        }
    }
    display(ans);
}
```

Comment: You set `ans` to NULL right after the malloc. This is wrong logically and also creates a memory leak.

Comment: Can you share the whole code, with `pushback()` and `node` definition?

Comment: `if ((a->data >= b->data) || (a == NULL && b!=NULL))` <<-- you dererefence a and b **before** testing if they are NULL

Comment: Your `while`condition means that one of `a` or `b` may be null, but not both. The `if` tests dereference `a` and `b`. Dereferencing a null pointer is illegal. In fact you have four cases: `a` is null: push `b`; `b` is null: push `a`; `a` is smaller than `b`: push `a`; otherwise push `b`.

Comment: Alternatively, you can test `while (a && b)` and then append the remaining elements of either `a` or `b` to the new list.

Comment: Also: the function could return (a pointer to) the resulting list (`ans`), instead of void. (or: does `pushback()` copy the elements?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void merge_sort(struct node *a, struct node *b)
{
    struct node *ans = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    ans = NULL;
    while (a != NULL && b != NULL)
    {
        
        if ((a->data >= b->data))
        {
            pushback(&ans, b->data);
            b = b->next;
            // display(ans);
        }
        else if ((b->data > a->data))
        {
            pushback(&ans, a->data);
            a = a->next;
            // display(ans);
        }
        
    }
    while(a != NULL)
    {
       pushback(&ans,a->data);
       a=a->next;
    }
    while(b != NULL)
    {
       pushback(&ans,b->data);
       b=b->next;
    }
    display(ans);
}
```

In your solution, you will miss out on the cases when the length of linked lists is not the same, and also the cases where the elements of a particular linked list get over. try this one, it will work out well if you have defined the `display()` and the `pushback()` functions correctly. 
 You must also mention the exact order in which the linked list are sorted(in that case, you might have to reverse the linked lists before applying this algorithm)

**it would be better if you provide the whole code which includes the definition of all the functions along with the output snippet, so that we can have idea of what might be the exact problem**

Comment: `else if ((b->data > a->data))` is redundant. `else` suffices.  This redundant test could actually cause an infinite loop if `data` has a floating point type and a NaN value.

Comment: `ans = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));` is useless and causes a memory leak.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach has multiple problems:

- you do not merge the lists, but attempt to construct a third list with the values from the 2 lists.
- you allocate an initial node to `ans`, but you immediately set `ans = NULL;` thereby losing the reference to the allocated memory, causing a memory leak.
- it is unclear what `push_back` does as it is not a standard function and you do not provide source code nor a specification.
- testing `(a->data >= b->data)` has undefined behavior if either `a` or `b` is a null pointer. You should test for the validity of the pointers **before** accessing the `data` members.
- `merge_sort` should return the new list `ans`.

Here is a modified version:

```
struct node *merge_sort(const struct node *a, const struct node *b)
{
    struct node *ans = NULL;
    while (a != NULL || b != NULL) {
        if (a != NULL && (b == NULL || a->data <= b->data)) {
            pushback(&ans, a->data);
            a = a->next;
        } else {
            pushback(&ans, b->data);
            b = b->next;
        }
    }
    //display(ans);
    return ans;
}
```

If you are supposed to *merge* the lists without allocating any memory, here is an alternative:

```
struct node *merge_sort(struct node *a, struct node *b)
{
    struct node *ans;
    struct node **link = &ans;

    while (a != NULL && b != NULL) {
        if (a->data <= b->data) {
            *link = a;
            link = &a->next;
            a = a->next;
        } else {
            *link = b;
            link = &b->next;
            b = b->next;
        }
    }
    *link = (a != NULL) ? a : b;
    //display(ans);
    return ans;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Standard solution, using a pointer-to-pointer:

---

```
struct node * merge_sort(struct node *one, struct node *two)
{
    struct node *ans , **pp;

    ans = NULL;
    for(pp = &ans; one && two; pp = &(*pp)->next) {
        
        if (one->data <= two->data) {
            *pp = one;
            one = one->next;
        }
        else    {
            *pp = two;
            two = two->next;
            }
        
    }
        /* At this point, either one or two is exhausted.
        ** or both: in that case NULL will be assigned to *pp
        */
    *pp = (one) ? one : two;

    return ans;
}
```

Comment: `ans = NULL;` is redundant.

Comment: That is correct. But it won't harm.